# Slider Header using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create an image like this using css.

[image: Slider Image Part]

which I partly achieved like this

```
<div class="nav-tab">
    <div class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.arrow {
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
    width: 240px;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/g3cmgw8y/6/
But the design has these problems

1) The `arrow-left` not having background-color transparent. ( Is it possible as per this design? )
2) What I want is to use it as the image below. When I put each `.nav-tab` in a `ul` > `li` with `float:left` the output is garbled.
[image: Slider Image Full]
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g3cmgw8y/7/

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this.

Comment: Not getting what's the issue? Is it that they won't come in single row(Same line)?

Answer (score 2):

How about using skew instead?

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/1gf3zam3/

```
<div class='arrow'>
<div class='arrowtop'>
</div>
<div class='arrowbottom'>
</div>
</div>

.arrowtop {

    transform: translateX(50px) skewX(45deg); 
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}

.arrowbottom {

    transform: translateX(50px) skewX(-45deg);
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... maybe this's an answer ?

```
.arrow-left {
  border-top: 30px solid green;
  border-bottom: 30px solid green;  
  border-left: 30px solid transparent; 
  position:relative;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your <li> tags works well ... you should just decrease width of image and you'll see a result.